# Printing a list returns the location of each element, not the values

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nodes

I am having issues printing a list that I am creating.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, cargo = None, next = None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next = next
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)

node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3

def printList(node):
    i = 0
    nodeList = []
    while node:
        nodeList.append(node)
        node = node.next
    return nodeList

print(printList(node1))
```

Here is the output:

```
[<__main__.Node object at 0x0189E470>, <__main__.Node object at 0x0189E950>, <__main__.Node object at 0x0189E7B0>]
```

I believe the output I am currently getting is the location that each element is being stored in my computer. The output I would like to recieve is [1, 2, 3] in a list format. I can do this by printing each element individually, but I would rather not. Can anyone offer me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nodeList` contains `Node` objects which is what you get in your print, **when printing the list**, so either call print on them:

instead of

`print(printList(node1))`

call

```
for nod in printList(node1):
    print(nod)
```

or make your `nodeList` contain string representation of nodes, since the function is called `printList`:

```
  def printList(node):
        i = 0
        nodeList = []
        while node:
            nodeList.append(str(node)) #use str() here
            node = node.next
        return nodeList

print(printList(node1))
```